# from where i can download sdk for Motorola MC3190?

Tags: sdk, windows-mobile, motorola, motorola-emdk

Where can I download the SDK for Motorola MC3190?  I checked the Motorola site - but can't find it.  Can I get any link for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of EMDK did you end up using? I am trying to develop an application for MC3190!

Answer (score 1):

Download it from [From Motorola's web site](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=99182&productDetailGUID=29d4d085364cf310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=2202caf8fb16e310VgnVCM1000000389bd0aRCRD).

Comment: Link dosen't provides the SDK instead it's going to default page, Can you update the link ?

Answer (score -1):

my platform is microsoft.net using c#,so i choose [EMDK FOR .NET 2.6](http://support.symbol.com/support/dynamickc.do?externalId=13480&sliceId=&command=show&forward=nonthreadedKC&kcId=13480&userId=37)

Comment: user1989339 or @Gali, the EMDK link doesn't work anymore.  I found the windows SDK at this updated location, but the MC3190 is not listed in the supported devices.  Is this the same SDK you are using? https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=87666&productDetailGUID=4a823b1ca4151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=928ad44a92151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD

Comment: Link is broken again. I don't know what Motorola is doing to their site.